# Run function if data changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, runonce

I am new in jQuery and can't figure how to succesfully run the script I use in my pages. The problem is I need to fade in and out text only if there are changes in my **load.php** file but not constantly like it is now, please help anyone... Many thanks!

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
$('#auto').load('load.php');

refresh();

});



function refresh()
{

    setTimeout(function() {


      $('#auto').fadeOut('fast').load('load.php').fadeIn('fast');

      refresh();
       }, 2000);

   }
```

Comment: is `load.php` returns some text?

Comment: @LovleshPokra Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function refresh()
{
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.get('load.php', function(data) {
      if (data !== $('#auto').html()) {
         $('#auto').fadeOut('fast').html(data).fadeIn('fast');
      }
      refresh();
    });
  }, 2000);
}
```

This makes the request outside of `load()`, and only fades in/out + replaces the content if it's different.

Comment: Something is not good with this code, I tried but it didn't work. :(

Comment: it was missing a closing `}`, maybe try again?

Comment: can you please also fix a milisec. before it load, it first show new version then it fade in, can it be frst fade in and THEN show new version ? (no problem if not!) Thanks, many!